# Interrupting a program (SIGINT) during a condition_variable::wait() call, with a subsequent call to exit(), causes it to freeze

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, condition-variable, resource-cleanup

I'm not sure I understand this issue very well, so I've written a small example program that demonstrates it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

class Application {
    std::mutex cvMutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread t2;
    bool ready = false;

    // I know I'm accessing this without a lock, please ignore that
    bool shuttingDown = false;

public:
    void mainThread() {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(this->cvMutex);

        while (!this->shuttingDown) {
            if (!this->ready) {
                std::cout << "Main thread waiting.\n" << std::flush;
                this->cv.wait(lock, [this] () {return this->ready;});
            }

            // Do the thing
            this->ready = false;
            std::cout << "Main thread notification recieved.\n" << std::flush;
        }
    };

    void notifyMainThread() {
        std::cout << "Notifying main thread.\n" << std::flush;
        this->cvMutex.lock();
        this->ready = true;
        this->cv.notify_all();
        this->cvMutex.unlock();
        std::cout << "Notified.\n" << std::flush;
    };

    void threadTwo() {
        while(!this->shuttingDown) {
            // Wait some seconds, then notify main thread
            std::cout << "Thread two sleeping for some seconds.\n" << std::flush;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
            std::cout << "Thread two calling notifyMainThread().\n" << std::flush;
            this->notifyMainThread();
        }

        std::cout << "Thread two exiting.\n" << std::flush;
    };

    void run() {
        this->t2 = std::thread(&Application::threadTwo, this);
        this->mainThread();

    };

    void shutdown() {
        this->shuttingDown = true;
        this->notifyMainThread();
        std::cout << "Joining thread two.\n" << std::flush;
        this->t2.join();
        std::cout << "Thread two joined.\n" << std::flush;
        // The following call causes the program to hang when triggered by a signal handler
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
};

auto app = Application();
int sigIntCount = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, [](int signum) {
        std::cout << "SIGINT recieved!\n" << std::flush;
        sigIntCount++;
        if (sigIntCount == 1) {
            // First SIGINT recieved, attempt a clean shutdown
            app.shutdown();
        } else {
            abort();
        }
    });

    app.run();

    return 0;
}
```

You can run the program online, here: https://onlinegdb.com/Bkjf-4RHP

The example above is a simple multithreaded application that consists of two threads. The main thread waits on a condition variable until a notification is received and `this->ready` has been set to `true`. The second thread simply updates `this->ready` and notifies the main thread, periodically. And finally, the application handles SIGINT **on the main thread**, where it attempts to perform a clean shutdown.

**The issue:**

When a SIGINT is triggered (via Ctrl+C), the application does not exit, despite calling `exit()` in `Application::shutdown()`.

This is what I think is happening:

1. The main thread is waiting for a notification, so it's being blocked by `this->cv.wait(lock, [this] () {return this->ready;});`
2. SIGINT is received, and the `wait()` call is interrupted by the signal, which results in the signal handler being invoked.
3. The signal handler calls `Application::shutdown()`, which subsequently calls `exit()`. The call to `exit()` hangs indefinitely because it's attempting some cleanup that cannot be achieved until the `wait()` call resumes (I'm not sure about this).

I'm really not sure about that last point, but this is why I think it's the case:

- When I remove the call to `exit()` in `Application::shutdown()` and let the `main()` return, the program exits without issue.
- When I replace the call to `exit()` with `abort()`, which does less in respect to cleanup, the program exits without issue (so this indicates that the cleanup process conducted by exit() is resulting in the freezing).
- If the SIGINT is sent when the main thread is **not** waiting on the condition variable, the program exits without issue.

The above is just an example of the issue I'm having. In my case, I need to call `exit()` in `shutdown()`, and `shutdown()` needs to be invoked from the signal handler. So far, my options seem to be:

- Move all signal handing into a dedicated thread. This would be a pain to do as it would require rewriting the code to enable me to call `Application::shutdown()` from a different thread as to the one that owns the instance to `Application`. I'd also need a way to pull the main thread out of the `wait()` call, likely by adding some `OR` condition to the predicate.
- Replace the call to `exit()` with a call to `abort()`. This would work but would result in the stack not being unwound (specifically, the `Application` instance).

Do I have any other options? Is there any way to properly interrupt a thread during a call to `std::condition_variable::wait()`, and exit the program from within the interrupt handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Igor, you can't really do much in signal handlers. You may operate on lock-free atomic variables though, so you could modify the code to work on that.

I've added that and made a few other changes and commented on my suggested changes in the code:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// Make sure the atomic type we'll operate on is lock-free.
static_assert(std::atomic<bool>::is_always_lock_free);

class Application {
    std::mutex cvMutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread t2;
    bool ready = false;

    static std::atomic<bool> shuttingDown;  // made it atomic

public:
    void mainThread() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cvMutex);

        while(!shuttingDown) {
            // There is no need to check  if(!ready)  here since
            // the condition in the cv.wait() lambda will be checked
            // before it is going to wait, like this:
            //
            // while(!ready) cv.wait(lock);

            std::cout << "Main thread waiting." << std::endl; // endl = newline + flush
            cv.wait(lock, [this] { return ready; });
            std::cout << "Main thread notification recieved." << std::endl;

            // Do the thing
            ready = false;
        }
    }

    void notifyMainThread() {
        { // lock scope - don't do manual lock() / unlock()-ing
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cvMutex);
            std::cout << "Notifying main thread." << std::endl;
            ready = true;
        }
        cv.notify_all(); // no need to hold lock when notifying
    }

    void threadTwo() {
        while(!shuttingDown) {
            // Wait some seconds, then notify main thread
            std::cout << "Thread two sleeping for some seconds." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
            std::cout << "Thread two calling notifyMainThread()." << std::endl;
            notifyMainThread();
        }
        std::cout << "Time to quit..." << std::endl;
        notifyMainThread();
        std::cout << "Thread two exiting." << std::endl;
    }

    void run() {
        // Installing the signal handler as part of starting the application.
        std::signal(SIGINT, [](int /* signum */) {
            // if we have received the signal before, abort.
            if(shuttingDown) abort();
            // First SIGINT recieved, attempt a clean shutdown
            shutdown();
        });

        t2 = std::thread(&Application::threadTwo, this);
        mainThread();

        // move join()ing out of the signal handler
        std::cout << "Joining thread two." << std::endl;
        t2.join();
        std::cout << "Thread two joined." << std::endl;
    }

    // This is made static. All instances of Application
    // will likely need to shutdown.
    static void shutdown() { shuttingDown = true; }
};

std::atomic<bool> Application::shuttingDown = false;

int main() {
    auto app = Application();
    app.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ted. Out of curiosity, what is the reason for avoiding manual locking (calls to `lock()` and `unlock()`)? Is it to avoid issues that could arise if an exception is thrown between the calls? Or is there another reason?

Comment: @JohnO'brien You are welcome! Yes, that's the main reason. The second reason is for readers of the code to not to get stuck. When reading code with manual resource management, I immediately start investigating if it could leak said resource. In your case I would have to check if `notify_all()` could throw. Well, it can't, but still. :-) It's good form to not leave anything out. Using a RAII wrapper even in short functions like this keeps it safe and simple and people reading the code won't spend time on irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 3):

> **[support.signal]/3** An evaluation is *signal-safe* unless it includes one of the following:
>
> (3.1) — a call to any standard library function, except for plain lock-free atomic operations and functions
> explicitly identified as signal-safe.
> ...
>
> A signal handler invocation has undefined behavior if it includes an evaluation that is not signal-safe.

Your program exhibits undefined behavior. A signal handler is very limited in what it can do safely.